# C# Create a map(shop layout plans) form local image(jpg,png) with marker,label,click handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-maps, dictionary

I want to create a map form , using the shop layout plans as a map,then can using a marker and add a label. also it can handle mouse move get the point to show the info.

I was found a map control like Gmap.NET ,SharpMap but it cannot set the local file(.jpg,.png) as map.If there any control or project can do that?

Comment: If you want to use Bing maps WPF control, you can create a MapLayer and image on it... Here is an example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh868032.aspx

Comment: If there a offline map control tool?prefer winform

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image as a 'marker' and overlay it on a map using Gmap.NET. You need to first create a GMapOverlay. Next, an instance of GMarkerGoogle is created. It takes two arguments: a location (a PointLatLng instance) and a marker type. For the marker type, there are a variety of marker images normally available in the Google Maps API (big balloons in many colors, small balloons in many colors, etc.). Or, you can supply an instance of Bitmap with your own image as shown below

```
GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528), new Bitmap("c:\images\mymarker.png");
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you need more details on the above example, you can refer to http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/

Comment: when I add the image set as markers not the layout map , if there can add other markers ,label cover in the image 'markers' ? also can get the point to show the info?because it is in the markers not the map layout ,  if you could let me know i will try.